# How to Access Camera and image data using Xamarin Portable

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am new to Xamarin, and Android.
I am only testing my app on Android as for now. Disabled ios and windows.

I want to get a stream of images from my camera, and do processing on that stream's data, as a stream of nXm matrices.

I can't figure out how to get the images as data matrices.
For that matter, I can't figure out even how to address my phone's camera on Xamarin.Forms (Portable).

All i found was this tutorial,

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/

which is Android specific, and doesn't give access to the data as raw matrix data

Please help

Comment: use the Xamarin.Media plugin to access the camera from a Forms app

Comment: @Jason allright, so https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-with-the-media-plugin-for-xamarin/ will allow me to capture an image using my camera. `var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions);` would capture an image and save it to "disk". I don't want that. I want the image in memory, in a format that enables processing (for example summing all the pixel data). How can this be done?
Thanks for refering me to the media plugin, that did help quite a bit

Comment: you'll need to read if from disk and convert it to a format that you want.  This may need to be done in a platform project and shared with your Forms code via DI.

Comment: @Jason this really makes no sense to me. the data goes from camera to memory to disk, then back to memory? Wouldn't this hurt performance? Also, what is DI?

Comment: Maintaining a large uncompressed bitmap in memory is expensive too.  If you want to try to stream a byte[] directly from the camera you may be able to do so with Android camera API.